# can i access variables in xml file?if yes then how?

Tags: java, android, xml

I written code for android platform.
i declare the variable sound_on_state integer variable in .java file
and in my sound.xml i written following code,

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                           
       android:oneshot="false">
<xsl:if sound_on_state > 0> /*this line give error as android prefix namespace*/
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sound_on_02" android:duration="50"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sound_on_01" android:duration="50"/>
<xsl:else>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sound_off_02" android:duration="50"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sound_off_01" android:duration="50"/>
</xsl:else>
</xsl:if>
</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. It should be done from the code. Add block of Views to a Layout, give it an ID, then in the code change its visibility according to whatever condition you want.